# how to get extension of file dragged file in javafx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to drag `.c` files into my javaFx TextArea,
So in case of an address it is possible by treating it as a string then check it extension with the "endswith(".c")" method, but I don't know how to do it if it is a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the extension with this from a `File` object:

```
String fileExtension = file.getName().substring( file.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

Plus the usual checks for null, index out of bounds, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the file names from the directory then use this code.

```
    File path = new File("D:" + File.separator + "MyDownloads");
    // Specify your directory
    File[] files = path.listFiles();
    StringBuffer cFiles = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(files[i].getName());
        if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".c")) {
            cFiles.append(files[i].getName() + "\n");
        }
    }
    // Give your text area variable in the place of textArea.
    textArea.setText(cFiles.toString());
```

cFile will give you the file names with extension "c" then set that text in your TextArea.